# Synchronizing SQLite with external SQL database server

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm building an android project which creates a SQLite database, stores some data in it and everything is fine.

I need my application to sync this data with a **SQL database server** located on a PC. The question is:

1. Can I do that?
2. What is the best practice for doing that?

Answer (score 3):

if you have to sync with webserver check this

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

SQLite has no built-in mechanism for synchronizing with a remote database. It is perfectly possible for you to write such a mechanism, though.

There may be some third-party solutions which can help you; have a look at [Zumero](http://zumero.com/), for example.